# How does a threading library know that a thread has finished its operation?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

Whatever it is, be it OpenMP, or posix threads, how do these libraries know when a thread is done with its job?

Comment: By "finished its operation" do you mean finished all operations it intends ever to perform, or do you mean finished *an* operation, such that it is ready for another to be provided to it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I meant the thread is done with its job, it has done all operations it wanted to perform. By "operation", I meant the thread's entire job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread explicitly, (calls some 'exitThread() API), or implicitly, (returns from the top level of the thread function, so implicitly resulting in an exitThread call), tells the OS to give it no more CPU and to release it's resources.

Answer (score 2):

In most threading libraries, the "main" routine that you provide for a thread isn't really the thread's "main" routine. A new thread typically starts by executing some library code, and *then* it calls your code, and finally it calls more library code after your code is "finished."  E.g.,

```
real_main_routine(caller_provided_main_routine) {
    initialize_stuff();
    try {
        caller_provided_main_routine();
    } catch (exception e) {
        maybe_do_something_with(e);
    }
    clean_stuff_up_and_die();
}
```

Somewhere within that `clean_stuff_up_and_die()` is where the library tells itself that the thread is finished.

Comment: Okay, and could you also tell me, how does a main thread (which created some other thread) kill that other running thread?

Comment: @ChonkieMongol it requests the OS to terminate the other thread.  Note that, with many apps, it is not defined behaviour to terminate threads except when the OS stops all threads at process termination, (may leave resources locked etc).

Comment: @ChonkieMongol, You can find lots of Q&A on this site about why it is unsafe to kill threads. Short version: Threads communicate with each other through shared data. If one thread forcibly kills another, that can leave shared data in a corrupted, unuseable state. The safe way to "kill" a thread is to send it a message or a signal or to set a flag AND, to design the thread so that it will safely clean up and shut itself down when it recognizes the message/signal/flag. Threads should always _cooperate_ with each other.